# get raw decimal value from mysqldb query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am executing a mysql query in python using the MySQLdb package.  The code looks something like this:

```
c=db.cursor()
c.execute("""select * from table""")
output = []
for row in c:
    output.append(row[4])
```

where `row[4]` contains a decimal value that I want to store in the `output` list.

The problem is every value that I am getting looks like this: `Decimal('XX.XX')` where all I want in the `output` list is XX.XX.  At the end of the script, my `output` list looks like this:

```
[Decimal('10.02'), Decimal('20.24'), ...]
```

But I need it to just contain the numbers, like this:

```
[10.02, 20.24, ...]
```

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can either convert a Decimal object to a string:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from table""")
output = []
for row in cursor:
    output.append(str(row[4]))
```

Or to a float:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from table""")
output = []
for row in cursor:
    output.append(float(row[4]))
```

Converting it to a float will cause it to lose its full precision, so a value like 20.24 will become 20.239999999999998.

Also, casting it to a float will raise an Exception if the value is `None`. To avoid that, you can use a helper function like this:

```
def convert_mysql_decimal_to_float(decimal_object):
    if (decimal_object == None):
        return None
    else:
        return float(decimal_object)

cell_value = convert_mysql_decimal_to_float(row[4])
```

Comment: Okay. We can easily convert the Decimal('XX.XX') to XX.XX. But why do we get the Decimal in first place. Ideally it should return an integer or float after querying right. Do we have any links of documentation giving an explanation of getting decimal. @Maksym Polshcha

Comment: @shreeshkatti - Decimals are precise while floats are imprecise, but Python doesn't have a native Decimal type like MySQL does. To avoid accidental data loss (such as 20.24 getting converted to 20.239999999999998), the module returns a special Decimal object so that you're forced to convert it by hand.

Answer (score 8):

Use `float()`:

```
output.append(float(row[4]))
```

But `float()` can result in something like:

```
In [184]: float(Decimal('10.02'))
Out[184]: 10.02

In [185]: float(Decimal('20.24'))
Out[185]: 20.239999999999998
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to write a generic code that operates on the column output, the above solution won't workout. In that case we can write our `SELECT` query in a way that the column in returned as String and we just get the value of what we want. 
The query can be framed in below way,

```
SELECT 
 CAST(COL1 AS CHAR) AS COL1,
 CAST(COL2 AS CHAR) AS COL2,
 .
 .
 .
FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid losing precision, you can use [Python's decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

```
from decimal import Decimal
c=db.cursor()
c.execute("""select * from table""")
output = []
for row in c:
    row_data = []
    for data in row:
        if type(data) is Decimal:
            row_data.append(float(data))
        else:
            row_data.append(str(dat))
        output.append(row_data)
```

Comment: Small point, but you need to indent the final line to include it with the rest of the code segment's formatting.

Comment: I don't think  "if type(data) is Decimal:"  is correct. There is no data type called as Decimal in python. How do you execute that ?

Comment: Okay we have to import Decimal from decimal