# How to Append "Decimal" from MySQL query result in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am running a MySql query in Python using the following code:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
query = ("""select sum(if(grade is not null,1,0)) as `test`,
    sum(if(grade < 7,1,0)) as `bad`,
    sum(if(grade < 7,1,0))/sum(if(grade is not null,1,0))*100 as `Pct Bad Grade`,
    student
    from grades_database
    where test_date >= '2014-08-01'
    group by student
    order by `Pct Bad Grade` desc;""")
cur.execute(query)
```

and I get a result something like

```
(Decimal('1'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('50.0000'), 'John Doe')
```

I need to remove the "Decimal" string in front of the values.

I tried using the following from [Past Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661999/get-raw-decimal-value-from-mysqldb-query)

```
output = []
for row in cur:
    output.append(float(row[0]))
print output
```

But it gives me this

```
[20.0, 5.0, 3.0, 7.0, 7.0, 2.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0,...]
```

Ideally I would like to rearrange the order of the the output and get something like

```
(John Doe, 50, 3, 1)]
```

from

```
(Decimal('1'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('50.0000'), 'John Doe')
```

Comment: `Decimal` objects are more precise than `float` objects. When you print or write the data you'll get just the numerical value, e.g.: `print Decimal('50.0000')` gives: `50.0000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your query to get the order you want (name then grades)

```
cur = conn.cursor()
query = ("""select student,
    sum(if(grade is not null,1,0)) as `test`,
    sum(if(grade < 7,1,0)) as `bad`,
    sum(if(grade < 7,1,0))/sum(if(grade is not null,1,0))*100 as `Pct Bad Grade`
    from grades_database
    where test_date >= '2014-08-01'
    group by student
    order by `Pct Bad Grade` desc;""")
cur.execute(query)
```

You can then change the values decimal, so skip the first index (the name).

```
for index, row in enumerate(cur):
    if index:
        output[index] = int(row)
print output
```