# Is there a way to call from Google Sheets (Or MySQL) with Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, discord, discord.py

I have this idea on my Discord Server which would allows people to do

```
?playtime [TheirID]
```

and it would display their playtime as a reply by my BOT(I am talking about their Unturned Server Playtime, which is explained below:)

Everyone's Unturned Server Playtime is stored in a Google Sheets table (It is also stored in a MySQL database), so is there a way to allow them to do ?Playtime and then their ID, it searches their ID, finds the row they are in and then embeds the whole row into a reply by the bot?

Any help will be appreciated, if you are confused please ask me more questions.

Comment: Look up libraries for asynchronous database access.  The `discord.py` module doesn't provide this, but there are other libraries that do that you can use in conjunction with `discord.py`

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I have now made it so it connects and displays data, the only issue is that instead of only displaying the number, it is displaying the following:
`Your Playtime on the Server is (Decimal('4.7650'),).`
Instead of:
`Your Playtime on the Server is 4.7650.`

My code:
https://hastebin.com/iyelahohev.py

Comment: Just do `float(row)`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661999/get-raw-decimal-value-from-mysqldb-query

Comment: It's still not working, I'm not sure where to put float(row); please can you show me where.

Comment: In `format` you would do something like `float(row[0])`

Comment: Okay, I got it to all work now. Thanks so much for helping me!

Comment: One more question, how do I make it so if they do ?playtime [SteamName] it will search through the "SteamName" column to find the right row. This is my code:
https://hastebin.com/metozagoya.py

Comment: Why do you have the `SteamName OR` part there at all?  I would just do `WHERE SteamName = %s`.  Also, see http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

Comment: I have the `OR` so people can either use their "SteamName" or their "SteamID", because the SteamID is an integer, and their SteamName is a string.

Comment: `Where %s in (SteamName, SteamID)` is probably what you want then. `SteamName OR SteamID IN (%s)` is parsed as `SteamName OR (SteamID IN (%s))`.  So any entry with a `SteamName` field will be selected

Comment: Alright, that works perfect. 
Say I wanted to send a different message if the whole string wasn't an integer, how would I do that?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Kwabs – I'm trying to make something very similar and came across your question while googling stuff. It sounds like you got your code working - would you be open to sharing it? I'm very interested to see how it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @user2957365 , sorry it has been over a month, but I just haven't checked this since then. I am happy to help you as I have got this, and much much more to work. Please contact me if you still need help.

Comment: @Mr.Kwabs no problem, and yes please! I've made some progress since then myself, but I would still love to have a look at what you've got. Thanks.

Comment: @user2957365 Alright, add me on Discord: Mr.Kwabs#9751

Comment: @Mr.Kwabs hey I'm not sure if you got my request, I sent it a few days ago. I'm Sidewinder#1671.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/)

It works well for discord bots