# executemany - Error message Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python and its environment.
I am using in-memory sqllite DB.
I am trying to query one of the table on my source ( My-SQL ) and put that data to in-memory table for some calculations.

Here are the details :

**Response from my source :**

```
  result =  [(Decimal('69.00000'), 'MachineA', 9827), (Decimal('72.00000'), 'MachineB', 9831)]
```

**Table in my sqllite ( In memory ) :**

```
CREATE TABLE calculation (calculation_value DECIMAL(10, 5),source_name varchar(100),source_id bigint)
```

Following is the code which I am using to insert values from source to `calculation` table.

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO calculation VALUES(?,?,?)", result)
```

But I am facing error following error :

**Exception Message  :** `('Error on line 335', 'InterfaceError', InterfaceError('Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.',))`

Error is thrown on following line :

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO calculation VALUES(?,?,?)", result)
```

It will be great if somebody could help me to understand the root cause as well.

Comment: can you also add the error the stmt is throwing ? Did an earlier command fail ?

Comment: Also your insert stmt needs to be "INSERT INTO calculation (calculation_value, source_name) VALUES (?, ?)"

Comment: Hey vin, thanks for you response, considering your second comment, I am using insert statement at other place as well and it is behaving correctly.
I think since my this resultset contains the column type `Decimal` in it, it is trying to insert `Decimal('69.00000')` in the column. I am not sure since I don't know how python and sqllite are treating this kind of data

Comment: hmm, seems like a type mismatch from the error. Can you try inserting everything as a string, the driver should handle conversion I guess..  what exactly is Decimal('69.00000') giving ?

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to do , I changed column to text, but still no success. Is it possible to get the back ground query ?

Comment: So this is working on my end, instead of Decimal (im not sure what this returns) use
`round(float(x), 5)`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Tyf1wxdg

Comment: @vin, please refer to my findings , when I try to insert  `test = [(Decimal('69.00000'), '46619ActiveEnergy', 9827)]` it gives me error and when I try to insert `test2 = [(69.00000, '46619ActiveEnergy', 9827)]` it is working perfectly.  Thanks for the example will go through that and will keep you posted. But Ideally this should be automatically done by python. I tried to change `Decimal` to `Numeric` but that also did not helped.Thanks for your help and time.Will get you back on the solution so that you can post it in answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get raw decimal value from mysqldb query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661999/get-raw-decimal-value-from-mysqldb-query)

Comment: Read this : https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/705mur/decimal_wrapper_in_tuple_prevents_insert_into/