# SQLLite - type casting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite

I am new to python.
I am moving my table data from AWS Redshift to in memory sqllite database in 
python.

Please refer the table structure below :

**Redshift Table :**

[image: s0 1]

My value field in the above column is in Decimal at Redshift.

When I tried to bring the data to sqllite , I found that the result which I am getting from Redshift contains `Decimal` keyword in the result so I was not able to insert it into the sqllite table which was also marked as Decimal ( Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058525/executemany-error-message-error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-typ?noredirect=1#comment93018476_53058525) for the same issue which I have raised earlier ). So I changed my datatype as varchar(30) so that my values can fit in the sqllite table.

Please refer the table structure below for my in memory sqllite table :

**in memory sqllite table**

[image]

Now I wanted to do the sum of the column value on the timestamp basis in my python script, but I am not able to get the expected result.

Here is the query which I am using in Redshift to get the sum and I am getting the expected output :

```
select sum(value) from table where id = 9831 and item_date = '2018-11-01' and to_char(item_datetime, 'HH24MI') between '0000' and '2359';
```

Here is the query which I am using in my script to type cast the value column to `decimal` and item_datetime to `strftime` to get the required output :

```
select sum(CAST(value as decimal)) from table where id = 9831 and item_date = '2018-11-01' and strftime(item_datetime, 'HH24MI') between '0000' and '2359';
```

But I am getting output as `None`.
Cloud somebody explain me this behavior and what I am doing wrong here ?
How to deal with this issue ?

Comment: Your previous solution was entirely the wrong one. Don't change the type of a column in order to store wrong data in it.  Anyway, as your screenshot shows you have a single quote mark at the end of every value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Thanks for your response , I would like to understand than what should be the approach to deal with this kind of data and how usually it is practiced in python.

Comment: As I thought you understood from that Reddit thread, you should convert your source data to use floats or ints, not strings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Yes now I find that it should be the better approach to convert them to float first and then insert into table rather than doing this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite it goes like this:

```
... AND STRFTIME('%H%M', item_datetime) BETWEEN '0000' AND '2359'
```

For more info see the [docs](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/strftime.php).

Comment: Thank you , so made my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am loosing the precision in my output, could you please throw some light on this as well.

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa Try using `DECIMAL(10,5)` in your SELECT.