# How to convert list of tuple cursor.fetchall to different format

Tags: python

My mysql query which is multiple joins `cursor.fetchall()` is giving the output below

`[('Books', Decimal('10.000'), Decimal('0E-20'), None), ('Pencil', Decimal('66.66666'), Decimal('0E-20'), None), ('Pen', Decimal('100.0000'), Decimal('0E-20'), None)]`

How to convert to below format

- round to two decimals
- None has to replace with 0

Expected out

`[('Books', '10.00', '0.00', 0), ('Pencil', '66.67','0.00', 0), ('Pen', '100.00', '0.00', 0)]`

Comment: You can do this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662016/4985099

Comment: Your (rounded) output has both strings and floating point numbers. The latter should not be rounded, because they can't always be considered exact. Do you want your rounded numbers to be of the Decimal type instead?

Comment: Basically i need to rounded of all integers and string if it is number and replace None to 0

Comment: use `for`-loop to change data in list.

Comment: For replacing None with 0, you can add constraint on your database to set default value of  filed to be 0 and add not null constrain, this will make sure you didn't get None while  queering the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal

sample = [
    ("Books", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
]

result = [(i, "%.2f" % j, "%.2f" % k, l if l else 0) for i, j, k, l in sample]
print(result)
```

### Output:

```
[
    ("Books", "10.00", "0.00", 0),
    ("Pencil", "66.67", "0.00", 0),
    ("Pen", "100.00", "0.00", 0),
]
```

Comment: NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined

Comment: @Nons you need to import it using `from decimal import Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in database functions to achieve this, instead of iterating the entire result set what will likely be twice.

```
SELECT column_1, ROUND(column_2, 2), ROUND(column_3, 2), COALESCE(column_4, 0) FROM table_name;
```